# How to use self.offset to drag sidemenu in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code for my side menu but I'm not able to set self.offset(x:, y:) as it says that the result is unused? How can I make this work as  I want the menu to be draggable to the left.

```
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in

            MenuView()
                .frame(width: 240, alignment: .leading)
                .background(Color.white)
                .offset(x: self.showMenu ? 0 : -geometry.size.width)
                .animation(.spring())
                .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                .zIndex(4)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { val in
                        self.offset(x: val.translation.width)
                    }
                    .onEnded { val in
                        self.offset(x: .zero)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As code is not testable, so just idea - scratchy. You cannot use `self` of View struct, change instead some state and use that state value in corresponding modifiers, like below

```
@Binding var showMenu: Bool

@State private var xOffset: CGFloat = .zero

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        GeometryReader { geometry in

        MenuView()
            .frame(width: 240, alignment: .leading)
            .background(Color.white)
            .offset(x: self.showMenu ? xOffset : -geometry.size.width)
            .animation(.spring())
            .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
            .zIndex(4)
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged { val in
                    self.xOffset = val.translation.width
                }
                .onEnded { val in
                    self.xOffset = .zero
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```